# How do I access paths with spaces in them in Perl on Windows?

Tags: windows, perl

I'm converting a Unix Perl script to run on Windows. I'm having a problem with paths that have spaces in them:

```
open (IN, "| C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.1\\bin\\mysql.exe -u root -ppwd") or die "$!";
```

The code above throws the following error:

`'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`

I tried wrapping in escaped `\"` like this:

```
open (IN, "| \"C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.1\\bin\\mysql.exe -u root -ppwd\"") or die "$!";
```

But no joy. How do I handle paths with spaces?

I'm using ActiveState v5.10.0 built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread.

Comment: Deleted my answer because I can't get the damn thing to work with just open, but this should do the trick for the moment: `chdir q!C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.1/bin!; open my $pipe, '|-', 'mysql.exe -u root -ppwd';`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are quoting the entire command, including the command-line arguments. You should have put your second escaped quote after the `mysql.exe`:

```
open (IN, "| \"C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.1\\bin\\mysql.exe\" -u root -ppwd") or die "$!";
```

You might also be interested in the `qq()` and `q()` operators, which allow you to use delimiters other than quotation marks to delimit strings. They are very helpful when you want to quote a string that includes quotes:

```
qq[| "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.1\\bin\\mysql.exe" -u root -ppwd]
```

Also, Perl will happily handle the correct path separator for command names (but not always for command arguments, so beware):

```
qq[| "C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.1/bin/mysql.exe" -u root -ppwd]
```

(And since this example doesn't need any interpolation, you could have used single-quotes or the `q()` construction:

```
'| "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.1\\bin\\mysql.exe" -u root -ppwd'
```

)

Answer (score 3):

It's Perl, so there are a 1000 ways (as you'll see),  One way (escape the spaces)

```
open (IN, "| C:\\Program\ Files\\MySQL\\MySQL\ Server\ 5.1\\bin\\mysql.exe -u root -ppwd") or die "$!";
```

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work. Even with \" wrapping the path it fails with the same error.

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the spaces as well.

```
open (IN, "| C:\\Program\ Files\\MySQL\\MySQL\ Server\ 5.1\\bin\\mysql.exe -u root -ppwd") or die "$!";
```

Or use the old [8.3 names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename):

```
open (IN, "| C:\\Progra~1\\MySQL\\MySQL~1\\bin\\mysql.exe -u root -ppwd") or die "$!";
```

Though, I have to question the sanity of piping the MySQL client, instead of just using [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.616/DBI.pm)

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to do this:

```
$mysql = "C:\\Program\ Files\\MySQL\\MySQL\ Server\ 5.1\\bin\\mysql.exe";
open (IN, "| \"$mysql\" -u root -ppwd") or die "$!";
```

**Update:**
I also noticed that as @mob rightfully points out I had my `\"` in the wrong place. Twenty five years of DOS and I miss that :/