# How to properly use filepath with arguments spaces in them, in Perl?

Tags: perl

Looking to open a file at `'"E:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vim\\vim73\\gvim.exe -f " %s" "'` and I'm getting `Cannot find e:\Program`.

What do I need to do to get it to work?

*edit*:  Here's the [script](http://pastebin.com/jgYuixke) I am trying to get working (it's the full script as I'm not yet familar with perl at all, sorry). It's supposed to launch gvim when I make a POST request to the server via chrome's TextAid. Check out line 38

Comment: I think this is the same question here [How do I access paths with spaces in them in Perl on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597463/how-do-i-access-paths-with-spaces-in-them-in-perl-on-windows)

Comment: Provide your buggy code so we can tell you what's wrong.

Comment: @ikegami seems like system launches the file, I should have been more clear in my question. Here's the script I am trying to get working. It's supposed to launch gvim when I make a POST request to the server via chrome's TextAid http://pastebin.com/jgYuixke Check out line 38

Comment: Now add the quotes I have in my answer.

Comment: Now your quotes are misplaced.

Comment: @ikegami Yeah, I'm all kinds of lost. Your answer solved the orignal example path I gave, but I realize the path string had a few arguments on the end. I also don't need to launch the application right away, I'm storing the string for later in the script. `'"E:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vim\\vim73\\gvim.exe -f " %s""'` doesn't work because of the two sets of double quotes. I've tried backslashing out the `%s` ones to no avail.

Comment: There isn't a problem at all here with *opening a file* with spaces in the path; you have a problem *shelling out to a program* with spaces in the name, which is different and (on windows) more difficult.

Comment: It would make life easier if you could post a few line example, rather than expect us to wade through 260 lines of mainly irrelevant code.

Answer (score 1):

It's either single\double-quoting the path or escaping the spaces with backslashes.

Comment: I've tried `"E:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vim\\vim73\\gvim.exe -f '%s'";` and it doesn't seem to be working: `'E:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`

Answer (score 1):

```
system
   sprintf
      '"E:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vim\\vim73\\gvim.exe" -f "%s"',
      $file;
```

Comment: Why not `system "E:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vim\\vim73\\gvim.exe", "-f", $file` ? Should work even on windows, probably better than the alternatives.

Comment: @hobbs, 1) The OP's program is not layed out that way. 2) Perl creates a flat command from the multi-arg version, so you might as well use a flat command to begin with.

Comment: It certainly *could* be laid out that way with 1 line of code change. And while perl *does* flatten the commandline to a string on windows, that's not *much* of a reason to write senseless nonportable code. Especially when the rules for the flattening are actually rather difficult

Comment: @hobbs, There are no rules for flattening. That's why it's better if you do it yourself than make Perl guess.

Answer (score 1):

I find it safer/easier to use forward slashes.

```
    my $file = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Reader 10.0/Reader/AcroRd32.exe' ;
    system $file ;
```

If you need parameters to the cmmmond

```
    my $file = '"C:/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Reader 10.0/Reader/AcroRd32.exe"' ;
    my $data = '"C:\working_dir/music/interim/a b.pdf"' ;
    system "$file $data" ;
```

Using single quotes makes it easier to embed double quites without having to escape things.

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this is to mess about with quoting and escapes.  You need to be sure to individually quote the command and each argument to the command as a separate string.

Also, on win32 you can use real slashes instead of backslashes for directory separators.  So:

```
system( sprintf '"E:/Program Files (x86)/Vim/vim73/gvim.exe" -f "%s"', $file );
```

The other, easier option is to use a list of arguments with `system()`.

Line 38:

```
my @EDITOR_COMMAND = ( 'E:/Program Files (x86)/Vim/vim73/gvim.exe', '-f' );
```

Line 185/186:

```
system( @EDITOR_COMMAND, $file );
```

Then all the pesky quoting is taken care of for you.

Comment: Re: "Also, on win32 you can use real slashes instead of backslashes for directory separators.", yes, but you're not using Win32 here, you're using `cmd`. Mind you, it accepts them too.

Answer (score 0):

```
our $EDITOR_CMD = "'E:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vim\\vim73\\gvim.exe' -f %s";
```